# How to use URL Pattern in chrome.cookies.get url field?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

When I use a URL Pattern in the url field of `chrome.cookies.get`, I am not able to retrieve a cookie. When I type in a full URL, I am able to get the cookie. Is it not possible to use a url pattern in the url field of chrome.cookies.get?

Basically, I am trying to show a certain div when the user first logs into the site, but only the first time. I figured I can achieve this by checking the session, and it looks like the JWT token changes on each new session.

I tried this: 
`chrome.cookies.get({url: '*://www.mysite.com/*', name: 'JWT'}, function (cookie) {...}` but it doesn't seem to work.

Do I need to use a full path? On https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll it says

> The URL with which the cookie to retrieve is associated. This
>   argument may be a full URL, in which case any data following the URL
>   path (e.g. the query string) is simply ignored. If host permissions
>   for this URL are not specified in the manifest file, the API call will
>   fail.

The 'may be a full URL' part makes me believe that you should be able to use a pattern in the URL field.

In my manifest file, I have

```
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "alarms",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "webNavigation",
    "pageCapture",
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabCapture",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
```

`"https://*/*"` should be able to match `*://www.mysite.com/*`.

Again, when I put the full url into the url field, I am able to get the cookie.

Comment: You're trying a URL pattern (not regex) where a URL is expected. I think you should simply specify `domain` instead. And use `getAll`, not `get`.